# Converting a string holding binary to float

Tags: c++, string, floating-point

I have a string holding a value in binary that I want to convert to float. I can't find a way to do this.

for example, I have a

```
string temp =  "00000000000000000000000101111100";
```

to represent 0.25 in binary.

Using `stof` on temp with `string::size_type` yields 1.0111110e+008 stored in the float variable (according to visual studio) and printing the value results in junk - 101111104.

My question: is there a way to convert the binary string to a float directly or would I need to calculate the float and then store it?

Comment: As texasbruce answered, you can acheive the same with bitsets as well. Demo: http://ideone.com/NQFXux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be one way

```
std::string temp = "00000000000000000000000101111100";
assert(temp.length() == 32);
int n = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < temp.length(); ++i)
{
    n |= (temp[i] - 48) << i;
}
float f = *(float *)&n;
```

Comment: hmm so apparently using cout to print the resulting float will print 0.25 but followed by many zeros - 0.25000000000, more than 100 of them

Comment: @abd Is it the same with `std::cout << 0.25f`?

Comment: Yes it is. I forgot I redefined its precision to do some testings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would convert to float, but you can convert to unsigned long using `std::bitset`

```
#include <bitset>

//...

std::string temp =  "00000000000000000000000101111100";
std::bitset<33> n (temp);
unsigned long result = n.to_ulong();
```

[REF](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

Of course you can cast unsigned long to float if  you want.

Comment: Well it is possible that my floats will be negative